# Swift 5: I Am Unable to Get My UITableView To Update In A Timely Manor (Using both `DispatchQueue.global().sync` and `DispatchQueue.main.async`

Tags: swift, multithreading, asynchronous

### Swift 5: I Am Unable to Get My UITableView To Update In A Timely Manor (Using both `DispatchQueue.global().sync` and `DispatchQueue.main.async`

**In a nutshell:**

- I have a simple **`for index in 1…20`** loop that does some "stuff."
- At the end of each of the 20 iterations I append a new element to the array that is the data source for my UITableView.
- I simply want the UITableView to update the display before starting the next iteration of the loop.

  - Is that really so much to ask? LOL

I've tried putting all the "work" on the background thread, I even created a thread with `QoSClass.utility`, and no matter what I do … it completely ignores all occurrences of `DispatchQueue.main.async` until the entire function has completed.

I have no problem getting done the work my code needs to accomplish.  My challenge at this point is controlling the order in which things are happening and getting the display to update (**AND remain responsive** to the user, which is currently **does NOT** do).

### EDIT/UPDATE:

**Using the answer below …** IF I use **`.async`** I get the timely updates that I desire BUT I don't get the index results in order 1, 2, 3 … 20. IF I use **`.sync`** I get the order that I want but NO updates. **How do I get my loop to execute IN ORDER and GET UPDATES to display once per loop?**

I am **VERY NEW to threading** here, so **please type slowly**.  Thank you!

Here's my VERY STRIPPED DOWN code:

```swift
//
//  ValidateViewController.swift
//  MySpecialProject
//
//  Created by Jim Termini on 10/16/21.
//

import UIKit
import PDFKit
import UniformTypeIdentifiers
import CoreData

class ValidateViewController: UIViewController, PDFViewDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!

    var statuses: [ValidationStatus] = []

    //
    //    START HERE: ViewDidLoad
    //
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        statuses = createStatusArray()
        tableView.delegate = self
        tableView.dataSource = self
    }


    //
    //    Button Pressed — Start Validating the Document!!
    //
    @IBAction func startValidatIn(_ sender: Any) {
        print("")
        print("")
        theMainThing()
        print("")
        print("")
    }


    //
    //    theMainThing function called when button pushed.
    //
    func theMainThing() {

        print("")
        print(pickedDocSourceFPnFURL ?? "No File Picked")


        let openResults = openFile(pdfURLToSearch: pickedDocSourceFPnFURL!)
        originalPDFDocument = openResults.0
        metaPDFModifiedDate = openResults.1

        var unaccountedPageCount = orginalDocumentPageCount


        // Keep track of the total number of Forms found in the Document
        var theFormCount = 0

        let JimmyQoS: DispatchQoS.QoSClass = DispatchQoS.QoSClass.utility
        let JimmysQue: DispatchQueue = DispatchQueue.global(qos: JimmyQoS)
        var countOfFormsOfThisPageLength: Int = 0
        var dummyVar: Int = 0


        for index in 1...20 {
            JimmysQue.sync {

                print("")

                if index == 6 {
                    //
                    //  Do special case stuff when index = 6
                    //
                } else if index == 1 {
                    //
                    //  Do special case stuff when index = 6
                    //
                } else {
                    //
                    //  Do regular case stuff when index = 2 – 5, 7 – 20.
                    //
                }

                print("")
                print("The NEXT Line is \"DispatchQueue.main.async\" SHOULD see GREEN row NEXT!!")


                DispatchQueue.main.async  {
                    print("\(Date())")
                    print("Here I am ... INSIDE the main thread async.")

                    if countOfFormsOfThisPageLength > 0 {
                        let term = (countOfFormsOfThisPageLength > 1) ? "forms" : "form"
                        self.statuses.append((ValidationStatus(image: StatusIcon.allGood,  title: "Identified \(countOfFormsOfThisPageLength) \(term) of \(index) pages each.", details: "Unaccounted for Pages: \(dummyVar) of \(self.orginalDocumentPageCount)")))
                        self.tableView.reloadData()
                        self.tableView.setNeedsDisplay()
                    }

                    print("This SHOULD be causing my display to update.")
                    print("\(Date())")
                }


                print("\(Date())")
                print("Here I am ... about to sleep the global (background) thread for 5 seconds to ensure the TableView is updated and displayed properly.")
                sleep(5)
                print("And here I am ... 5 seconds later ... still no UIViewTable Update :-(")
                print("\(Date())")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the walk-thru of what does and should happen…

- I push the Start Validate button
- Two rows of purple/green print ✅
- `theMainThing()` function is called ✅
- One row of red/yellow prints ✅
- The `for index in 1…20` loop starts ✅

  - The yellow line prints at the start of each loop ✅
  - My processing DOES do what it is supposed to do ✅
  - A red line prints before the `DispatchQueue.main.async` block is **SUPPOSED** to execute, at a **higher priority**, updating the `UITableView`. ✅
  - The main (UI) thread is supposed to kick off and ❌

    - Print a green row ❌
    - Update the UITableView/display ❌
    - Print a 2nd green row ❌
  - To give the UI time to update … I

    - Print a purple row ✅
    - Sleep the background queue for 5 seconds ✅
    - Print another purple row ✅

And this is my **ACTUAL** console output:

### The green lines, from the high priority main thread, are not executing until AFTER the `for index in 1…20` loop completes + AFTER the `theMainThing()` function completes + AFTER the `startValidatIn(_ sender: Any)` function completes‼️

```swift
The NEXT Line is "DispatchQueue.main.async" SHOULD see GREEN row NEXT!!
2021-10-17 02:34:21 +0000
Here I am ... about to sleep the global (background) thread for 5 seconds
to ensure the TableView is updated and displayed properly.
And here I am ... 5 seconds later ... still no UIViewTable Update :-(
2021-10-17 02:34:26 +0000


-------------------------
18 Duplicate Sets Omitted
-------------------------




The NEXT Line is "DispatchQueue.main.async" SHOULD see GREEN row NEXT!!
2021-10-17 02:34:26 +0000
Here I am ... about to sleep the global (background) thread for 5 seconds
to ensure the TableView is updated and displayed properly.
And here I am ... 5 seconds later ... still no UIViewTable Update :-(
2021-10-17 02:34:31 +0000




2021-10-17 02:46:34 +0000
Here I am ... INSIDE the main thread async.
This SHOULD be causing my display to update.
2021-10-17 02:46:34 +0000
2021-10-17 02:46:34 +0000
Here I am ... INSIDE the main thread async.
This SHOULD be causing my display to update.
2021-10-17 02:46:34 +0000
```

This is what my console output **SHOULD** be:

### After every red line should be a green line from the high priority main UI thread.

```swift
The NEXT Line is "DispatchQueue.main.async" SHOULD see GREEN row NEXT!!
2021-10-17 02:46:34 +0000
Here I am ... INSIDE the main thread async.
This SHOULD be causing my display to update.
2021-10-17 02:46:34 +0000
2021-10-17 02:34:21 +0000
Here I am ... about to sleep the global (background) thread for 5 seconds
to ensure the TableView is updated and displayed properly.
And here I am ... 5 seconds later ... still no UIViewTable Update :-(
2021-10-17 02:34:26 +0000



The NEXT Line is "DispatchQueue.main.async" SHOULD see GREEN row NEXT!!
2021-10-17 02:46:34 +0000
Here I am ... INSIDE the main thread async.
This SHOULD be causing my display to update.
2021-10-17 02:46:34 +0000
2021-10-17 02:34:26 +0000
Here I am ... about to sleep the global (background) thread for 5 seconds
to ensure the TableView is updated and displayed properly.
And here I am ... 5 seconds later ... still no UIViewTable Update :-(
2021-10-17 02:34:31 +0000
```

Comment: If you really don't grok threading, and if you can confine your app to iOS 15 and later, you will be a _lot_ happier using the wonderful new async/await stuff.

Answer (score 1):

When the user clicks the button, you are on the Main Thread; it's handling that button click event.

While handling that event, you then create a queue `JimmysQue` and execute a synchronous operation on it with `JimmysQue.sync { ... }`.

By calling `sync` you are saying "I want to perform this operation on another queue, but I also want to (synchronously) wait until that other queue is done.  In other words **you've put the Main Thread on pause** until the block you've dispatched to `JimmysQue` completes.

When running that background action, `JimmysQue` calls `DispatchQueue.main.async`.  A *conceptual model* you might associate with this is "send an event to the main event event loop that will run this block of code when no other events are being handled."

But remember, the Main Thread is still handling your click event!  You pasused it until `JimmysQue` could finish running its block.  So that thing you've dispatched to the main thread won't run until your button handler finishes and your button handler is still waiting on the rest of the activity you've sent to `JimmysQue`.

The simple change that I think will get you the effect you're after is to dispatch your block to `JimmysQue` using  `async` instead of `sync`.

The validation block will be sent off to run in the background. The Main Thread won't wait on it (the button click event will finish and the Main Thread will go off to handle any other events).

Then when the block on `JimmysQue` finishes validating it will send the block using `DispatchQueue.main.async` to be executed on the Main Thread when it has some free time.

I... typed... this... very... slowly...

Here's an even more stripped down example that demonstrates the general flow.  You can paste this in a Playground. Try changing the call from `async` to `sync` on the `.utility` queue to see how the behavior changes.

```
import Foundation

func theMainThing() {
    print("Dispatching blocks from main thread")

    for index in 1...20 {
        DispatchQueue.global(qos: .utility).async {

            // Sleep for a random amount of time to simulate a long
            // running Action
            sleep((1...5).randomElement()!)

            DispatchQueue.main.async  {
                print("The main thing's index number \(index) completed")
            }
        }
    }

    print("The Main Thread has gone on to bigger and better things")
}

theMainThing()
```

In comments you asked about ordering the completion of the results.  Here's an example of that:

```
import Foundation

    func theMainThing() {
        print("Dispatching Async blocks from main thread")

        let scottsQueue = DispatchQueue(label: "ValidationQueue", qos: .utility)

        for index in 1...20 {
            scottsQueue.async {
                print("The starting item \(index)")

                // Sleep for a random amount of time to simulate a long
                // running Action
                sleep((1...5).randomElement()!)
                DispatchQueue.main.sync {
                    print("The main thing's index number \(index) completed")
                }
            }
        }

        print("The Main Thread has gone on to bigger and better things")
    }

    theMainThing()
```

Note that we put all the validation blocks into a serial queue so they are executed strictly in order.  Each block dispatches to the main queue using `sync` so each background task waits for the Main Queue to acknowledge the completion before it completes.

Comment: Thank You‼️ IF I use `.async` I get the timely updates that I desire BUT I don't get the index results in order 1, 2, 3… 20.  IF I use `.sync` I get the order that I want but NO updates.  How do I get my loop to execute IN ORDER and GET UPDATES to display once per loop?  AND Thank you for typing slowly! LOL

Comment: The first thing you want to do is create a serial queue so that the blocks you send to the queue are executed one after the other.  The second block you dispatch won't execute until the first one completes.  Then you change the call to `Dispatch.main` to be `Dispatch.main.sync`.  That way the *background* thread will be paused each time until the main thread gets around to finishing.

Comment: I added s second code example demonstrating the ordering of the results.